# Compact manifold is $\sigma$-compact

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $d,k \in \mathbb{N}$. A $d$-dimensional $C^k$-manifold is a topological space $M$ equipped with a set $(O^i,k^i)_{i \in \mathcal{I}}$, with, for each $i \in \mathcal{I}$, $O^i$ is an open subset of $M$ and $k^i$ a map from $O^i$ into $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ such that:

i) the open sets $O^i$, $i \in \mathcal{I}$, over $M$;

ii) $k^i(O^i)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$;

iii) for each $i \in \mathcal{I}$ the map $k^i: O^i \longrightarrow k^i(O^i)$ is a homeomorphism;

iv) If $O^{ij}=O^i\cap O^j \neq \emptyset$, then for $W^l=k^l(O^{ij}) \subset k^l(O^l)$, $l=i$ or $j$, the map $k^{ij}:W^i \longrightarrow W^j$ given by $k^j \circ (k^i)^{-1}$ is a $C^k$-diffeomorphism.

**Definition:** A manifold $M$ is $\sigma-$compact if there exists a sequence of compact set $K^0 \subset K^1 \subset \dots \subset K^n \subset \dots$ such that $$K^n \subset \operatorname{int} K^{n+1}   \hbox{ and } M=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} K^n.$$

With this definition, can I say that all compact manifold $M=K$ is $\sigma$-compact?

**My attempt:** Taking $K^n=K$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we obtain $\operatorname{int} K^{n+1} = \operatorname{int} K= K$, since $K=\operatorname{int} K$ by the definition of topology. Hence, $K^n = K \subset K=\operatorname{int} K^{n+1}$. Also, $M=K=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} K_n$. It seems to be something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is true,  since the manifold is the union of one compact manifold,  namely itself.

Comment: I could not link your suggestion with the above definition.  Your suggestion works well when you don't have the first condition ($K^n \subset \operatorname{int} K^{n+1}$) and the amount of compacts can be finite, that is, the usual definition of $\sigma-$compact.

Comment: @VictorHugo: It works just fine in the compact case. If you define $K^1$, $K^2$, $K^3$, etc., to all be equal to $M$, then $K^n \subseteq \operatorname{int} K^{n+1}$ and $M = \bigcup_n K^n$. (Note that the interior of $M$ is $M$ itself.)

Comment: Thank you so much @JackLee!

Comment: @VictorHugo: you’re welcome!